# Relative Clauses and Adjective Placement

Tags: adjectives, relative-clauses, i-adjectives, word-order

How would you add adjectives inside a relative clause to the thing being modified?  Is the placement set?

For example, in this sentence, can "new" come directly before computer (1) or should it be within the clause (2) or would even outside the clause be preferred (3)?

妹は学校に(3)お母さんが(2)買った(1)パソコンを持ってくる。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think (1) is best. (2) is unnatural. If you want to place 新しい at (2), you need to change 新しい to the continuative form of it, which is 新しく, because the adjective modifies a verb 買う.

You can place 新しい or 新しく at (3), but If 新しい is placed at (3), a comma is necessary between 新しい and お母さん because it can mean 新しいお母さん(new mother).

Comment: If it were at (3), wouldn't it become "the computer that her 'new mom' bought"? Or does no such misunderstanding happen because of context?

Comment: @Sweeper Haha, I didn't think of "new mother". Yes, it can mean "new mother", but what is "new mother"? If 新しい is placed at (3), a comma is necessary between 新しい and お母さん

Comment: FYI 新しく is not called the “て form”, it’s the 連用形 or “continuative form”. You could also call it “adverbial form” (which is more understandable but less precise).

Comment: @Darius Jahandarie I heard 連用形 is taught as て form to non-Japanese people. Is it wrong?

Comment: The て form is the form that has the て in it (新しくて). I’m sure there’s some textbooks or teachers which confuse the different forms, but that’s nothing to emulate...

Comment: @Darius Jahandarie Do you say that 新しく in 新しくて is the て form and 新しく in 新しく買う is the continuative form? But they are the same, aren't they? Or do you say that 新しくて itself, that is "including て", is て form?

Comment: Yes, “including て” is what I call the て form. You could say “stem of the て form”, but in the case of verbs I think that would better be used when you are trying to refer to the 音便形 (i.e., 行っ instead of 行き).

Comment: @Darius Jahandarie Thank you. I got it. I am not familiar with how non-Japanese people are taught Japanese language.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is fantastic information.  So, if 新しい was placed at 2 and the form not changed to くwould it be outright wrong or just unnatural?

Comment: @Strawberry  Generally, a modifier is placed just before a modified word, so I feel お母さんが新しい買ったパソコン is unnatural.